# Why do JIT Compiler need to translate bytecode to another intermediate representation before generating machine code

Tags: java, jvm, jit, jrockit

I am studying about JVM using the excellent book [Oracle JRockit: The Definite Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847198066). One thing I doesn't really get is the need of JIT compiler to translate bytecode to another intermediate representation (IR), optimize them then translate to native code.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation), bytecode is already a type of IR. Why JIT compiler in JRockit doesn't optimize the bytecode directly? My guess is it is harder to perform optimization on bytecode than on another IR (for example: C) but I am not sure at all.

Comment: It is not *needed*, it’s a *design decision* made for a particular JVM implementation, hence, this decision may have implementation specific reasons.

Comment: Different IRs serve for different purposes. Even one compiler often uses multiple IRs during different phases of compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Some optimizations depend on target architecture (instruction set, etc.) and therefore aren't possible on bytecode, which is architecture-independent.